# Resolving Promises asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have 2 different loops that perform POST and DELETE operations respectively.
Once, the all the operations are complete, I want to make another service request.

my issue is: 
In case of error on delete operation, the control goes to the catch block and a dialog confirmation is needed to decide if the item still needs to be deleted.

If a confirmation comes from the dialog, I want to make a permanent delete to the id and which is happening. But Somehow refresh is invoked earlier than I want. I miss something fundamental here.

```
function submitAndRefresh(){
    var deletePromisesTasks = [];
    var addPromisesTasks = [];

    angular.forEach(toBeDeleted, function(value,key){
        deletePromisesTasks.push(delete(value.id));
    });

    angular.forEach(toBeAdded, function(value,key){
        addPromisesTasks.push(add(value));
    });

    //To be performed after all the add/delete operations are completely done!  
    $q.all(deletePromisesTasks,addPromisesTasks).then(function(){
        refreshData(); //Another Service Call
    });
}

function delete(id, purge_flag) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        deleteOrPurge(id, purge_flag).then((promise1) => {
            defer.resolve();
        }).catch(function(error) {
                confirmAndDeleteContractParameters(error, delete, id, true);
        }).finally(function(){
            return defer.promise;
        });
    }

function deleteOrPurge(id, purge_flag){
    return Service.items().delete({
       id: id,
       purge_flag: purge_flag || false
       }).$promise;
}



function confirmAndDelete(error, callback, parameterId, purge_flag) {
        var confirmModal = {
            header: 'Confirm',
            showCancelButton: true
        };
        try {
            confirmModal.body = 'Some msg. Do you want to continue?';
        } catch (e) {}
        ModalService.confirmDialog($scope, confirmModal, function(confirm){
            if (confirm) {
                callback(parameterId, purge_flag);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `finally(function(){
            return defer.promise;
        }` does not return from `function delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic rule, when you have a function started with `var defer = $q.defer();`, the last line of the function should usually be `return defer.promise`